# Clarification On Firebase Denormalization Blog Post

Tags: firebase, denormalization

I just read the Firebase blog post titled [Denormalizing Your Data Is Normal](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-04-12-denormalizing-is-normal.html), and I have request for clarification.

I was with it until the Considerations paragraph.  Specifically, the following:

"Modification of comments is easy: just set the value of the comment under /comments to the new content. For deletion, simply delete the comment from /comments — and whenever you come across a comment ID elsewhere in your code that doesn’t exist in /comments, you can assume it was deleted and proceed normally"

For modifications, why don't I have to modify the duplicate comments stored under /links and /users?

For deletions, am I correct in my understanding that once I delete a comment I have to have logic in all my read logic to cross-check /comments in case it was deleted?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The structure detailed in the blog post does not store duplicate comments. We store comments once under `/comments` then store the `name` of those comments under `/links` and `/users`. These function as pointers to the actual comment data.

Consider the example structure from the post...

```
{
  users: {
    user1: {
      name: "Alice",
      comments: {
        comment1: true
      }
    },
  },
  comments: {
    comment1: {
      body: "This is awesome!",
      author: "user1"
    }
  }
}
```

Note that the actual comment data is only stored once.

If we modify `/comments/comment1`, we don't need to update anything else because we only store the `name` of the comment under `/links` and `/users`, not the actual comment contents.

If we were to remove `/comments/comment1`, that would remove the only existence of the comment data. However, we still have these "dangling" references to `comment1` under `/users/user1/comments`.

Imagine we delete `/comments/comment1`, when we try to load Alice's comments, we can look and see that `comment1` doesn't exist anymore. Then our application can react accordingly by either a) deleting the reference or b) ignoring the reference and not trying to display the deleted comment.

Comment: Sorry for missing the .set(true) bit.  Makes perfect sense now.  Thanks so much for clarifying this for me!

Comment: What should I do if I rename the "comment1" to "comment2" for example? (in my case, the username can be renamed)

Comment: The trick there would be to use a unique user identifier which isn't a username. You could user ref.push().name() to get a GUID-like string which you would use in place of "user1" then if the username changes, change a username field on that object instead of the GUID.

Comment: Another doubt I have on the same is how does this scale. Say, I am using a mobile app and using an Object to serialize the Users, Comments, etc. when I read the object, the comments array could be super huge. What if there are thousands of comments, will it all be fetched? Won't it create a mess?